# Is there a way to copy an existing library but being able to modify the new one?

Tags: cmake

I need to be able to create a new library from an existing one. For example, I would like to be able to copy Qt5::Widgets and create a library with an other name, but with every setting staying the same. Later, I would change some locations on the newly made library without changing the original library.

An example can help to understad:

I have Qt5::Widgets and would like to make an exact copy of said library and call it ModifiedQt5Widgets. I want every property to be the same. Then, I would modify some properties such as `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` on this new library. I also want this new library to behave the same as Qt5::Widgets when I link it. This seems to be difficult since this is an imported library. Is there a function or a way to just do like `copy_existing_library(ModifiedQt5Widgets Qt5::Widgets)`?

Basically, I want to make an alias library, but I want to be able to edit this new library.

*Edit*

My use case is that I have 4 possible configurations: Debug, MinSizeRel, RelWithDebInfo, Release. This is the tree that I will have in my build folder:

```
├── bin
|   ├── Debug
|   ├── RelWithDebInfo
|   ├── MinSizeRel
|   └── Release
```

I have a bunch of external libraries that I link to. I need to be able to link to these libraries, and then copy all these shared libraries in the appropriate `bin/[CONFIGURATION]` folder. Once that it compiled, I need my generated project in each folder to have all external dependencies to be in the same folder and be independent of the environment.

Also, this needs to work on Mac, Windows, and Linux. It seems that Windows may have issues with a solution based on using `RPATH`. I also need a way to find the `dll`s that match the `lib`s that I link with.

Comment: " Then, I would modify some properties such as IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG on this new library." - Smells like a **XY problem**. What do you want to achieve finally?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do understand that what I am doing is not orthodox by any means, but basically, for packaging and distribution reasons, I need to copy all library files needed by my CMake project and add them into my binary folder. Instead of linking with the external files, I first copy the needed file in my bin folder and then link with that file. The problem is with imported targets such as Qt5::Widgets. Calling `target_link_libraries` on such library does more than just link, but also adds include directories and other flags. I need a way to still link to a file in my bin folder.

Comment: "Instead of linking with the external files, I first copy the needed file in my bin folder and then link with that file." - While both files (original and copied one) exist at the time of linking, it has **no difference** whether you link to original or copied one. That is, even after copy the file, you may still link with original one. Which file will be chosen at runtime depends on RPATH settings. And it is you who can control these settings.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So, for my current use case, I should use `BUILD_RPATH`? What if I have a library that has one file for `Debug` and an other one for `Release`? Is there a way to set an `RPATH` based on what configuration you are in? My current structure is that I have a `bin/Debug`, `bin/MinSizeRel`, etc, and I would like to set the `RPATH` to each folder depending on what configuration I am on. What property would I set for that?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I also edited my original post to better explain my whole situation.

Comment: On Windows RPATH settings are useless, and on Linux you will most likely use `Makefile` generator, which is single-configuration one. So you may easy `if()`/`elseif()` on `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and choose appropriate RPATH. As for generic RPATH in multi-configuration generator, see e.g. [this mailing](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2017-June/030106.html).